# obtain common.logging.dll for visual studio.net 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I would like to download a version for C# 2008 of the common.logging.dll from the followinng url:
http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/.

Do you know how I can obtain a download to the version I need? If so, can you tell me how to access the version I need?

Answer (score 1):

In the [downloads](https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/downloads) page referred in your link there are zips.

Inside the zip of the latest version there is a folder `bin\net\2.0`  which I assume should contain dlls compatible with .Net 2.0 which should work with VS 2008.